# Lightning Interface and Knowledge Base

Tags: knowledge, lightning

I'm brand new on Lightning and I would like some help. Do you know if knowledge base can be added on lightning interface and what can be added to lightning interface regarding cases?

Comment: Hi Barbara, I would recommend you open a new question for lightning interface for cases (if you still wonder what the difference is) cheers!

Comment: if the below post provided useful, consider accepting it as an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in regards to "Do you know if knowledge base can be added on lightning interface "

Lightning Knowledge has been around for a year or so, you can enable it and add the tab to any of your apps (or create a specific knowledge app):

[image]

If you are migrating from knowledge to lightning knowledge, I would recommend you go through the [Lightning Knowledge Guide (Beta) - Salesforce](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1hMPApLHVAhUk1oMKHWGDC1QQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.docs.salesforce.com%2F208%2Flatest%2Fen-us%2Fsfdc%2Fpdf%2Flightning_knowledge_guide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHfDgG50D9p4e-oKWsOiMS_xVWW8A) since it is still in Beta, and there are a number of limitations.